# .setText() not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a function which by design should:

1. Create new directory
2. Copy docs from specified dir to newly created one
3. Set text to that copied docs

And I implemented it in such way:

```
function copyDocsAndSetText(fromDirId, toDirId) {
  var toDir = DriveApp.openFolderById(toDirId);
  var cwd = toDir.createFolder("New folder");

  var fromDir = DriveApp.openFolderById(fromDirId);
  var originalFiles = fromDir.getFiles();
  while (originalFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = originalFiles.next();
    file.makeCopy(cwd);
  }

  var copiedFiles = cwd.getFiles();
  while (copiedFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = copiedFiles.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    doc.getBody().setText("It works!");
  }
}
```

I should see "It works!" as a content of each file inside newly created directory but I don't. What I'm doing wrong? Or it is some kind of bug?

Comment: Sanity check: [`doc.saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose())

Comment: @Emissary much obliged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a small mistake, replace `openFolderById` with `getFolderById`

```
var toDir = DriveApp.getFolderById(toDirId);
var fromDir = DriveApp.getFolderById(fromDirId);
```

Comment: Is it working now? If so, You can mark it as answer ;)

Comment: The actual answer is @Emissary's .saveAndClose()

Comment: Sorry for a late coming mark, I assume it is correct, thou I'm not able to recollect wether it actually was